# Constructing a 1-planar graph that has no rectilinear drawing

Tags: graph-theory, graph-drawing

A 1-planar graph is a graph that can be drawn in the Euclidean plane in such a way that each edge has at most one crossing point, where it crosses a single additional edge.
[1 planar graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1-planar_graph)

I read the following paper, which stated the following fact about the rectilinear drawing of a 1-plane graph.

**Thomassen, C. (1988), Rectilinear drawings of graphs. J. Graph Theory, 12: 335-341.**https://doi.org/10.1002/jgt.3190120306

**Theorem 3.1.** Let $G$ be a graph represented as a normal drawing of index $0$ or $1$. Then there exists a rectilinear drawing equivalent to $G$ if and only if $G$ contains no $B-$ or $W-$configuration.
[image]

From this theorem we know that a 1-planar graph satisfies **any 1-plane drawing** of it without $B-$ and $W-$configuration, then it has no rectilinear drawing.

But I haven't constructed a 1-planar graph without rectilinear drawing so far. It is even doubtful that it exists. This is one of my confusing points. Any advice would be helpful and thanks in advance!

**Some concepts are added below:**

- Every finite graph can be drawn in the Euclidean plane such that **any two edges
  have at most one point in common** (in particular, **two edges with a common end
  have no other point in common**), and such that **every point that is not a vertex**
  and that is on two edges is on precisely two edges and is a cross-point for these
  two edges. We call such a **drawing normal**.
- The **maximum number of crosspoints
  on an edge** is called the **cross-index** of the drawing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main result of the following paper states that a graph which has a 1-planar straight-line drawing has at most $4n-9$ edges, where $n$ is (as usual) the number of vertices:

*Didimo, Walter*, [**Density of straight-line 1-planar graph drawings**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.ipl.2013.01.013), Inf. Process. Lett. 113, No. 7, 236-240 (2013). [ZBL1259.05107](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1259.05107).

On the other hand, it is not hard to come up with a 1-planar graph with $4n-8$ edges: take any drawing of a planar graph in which every face is a quadrilateral and add a pair of crossing edges to each face. For instance, applying this to the cube gives $K_8$ with a matching removed.

Comment: Great!  thanks for your help！